# 4 Excel Formulas into 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Good Morning

I want to write a single excel formula to populate a price from a list of prices:

```
Quantity    Cost
Between 30-50 Shirts    £15.00
Between 51-100 Shirts   £13.75
Between 101-300 Shirts  £13.00
Between 301-500 Shirts  £12.50
```

I have figured out how to do the formulas individually but is there an easier way as one line of formula, I am sure there is but my brain cannot seem to remember:

```
=IF(A2<=50,I2,)
=IF((AND(A2>50, A2<=100)), I3,)
=IF((AND(A2>=101, A2<=300)), I4,)
=IF(A2>=301,I5,)
```

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: This has now been solved, thank you all.

Comment: That's great. Please don't forget to actually close the thread by accepting an answer. See the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are unfamiliar with the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Consolidate all you formula to a single formula like below-

```
=IF(A2<=50,I2,IF(AND(A2>50, A2<=100), I3,IF(AND(A2>=101, A2<=300), I4,IF(A2>=301,I5,""))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already done most of the work:

```
=IF(A2<=50,I2,)
=IF((AND(A2>50, A2<=100)), I3,)
=IF((AND(A2>=101, A2<=300)), I4,)
=IF(A2>=301,I5,)
```

However, there is one thing missing: in your latest formula, the "else" is not filled in, I'll put there "-1" instead. Now, let's align your formulas:

```
=IF(A2<=50,I2,  )
              IF((AND(A2>50,A2<=100)),I3,  )
                                         IF((AND(A2>=101,A2<=300)),I4,  )
                                                                      IF(A2>=301,I5,-1)
```

Once you have this, just move the closing brackets up to the end of the formula:

```
=IF(A2<=50,I2,  
              IF((AND(A2>50,A2<=100)),I3,  
                                         IF((AND(A2>=101,A2<=300)),I4,  
                                                                      IF(A2>=301,I5,-1))))
```

Remove the newline characters (just put everything on one line):

```
=IF(A2<=50,I2,IF((AND(A2>50,A2<=100)),I3,IF((AND(A2>=101,A2<=300)),I4,IF(A2>=301,I5,-1))))
```

Good luck

P.s. If I can give you a piece of advise: put the original list of formulas in a comment next to the final formula: if ever you need to modify something, this will make it easier to understand how you created this long formula.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little bit of an alternative for you:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=INDEX(I2:I5,MATCH(A2,{1,51,101,301}))
```